# A math logic problem

Tags: logic, recreational-mathematics, problem-solving, puzzle, word-problem

Say there are 12 people on an island, 11 weigh the same.

One is either lighter or heavier.
There's a beam balance to measure the weights.
Is it possible to find the *heavier OR lighter* person in only 3 attempts?

I've tried a few approaches but they take 4 attempts, anyone can do it in 3?

Comment: What did you try exactly, which takes $4$ attempts?

Comment: Maybe, [this](https://medium.com/big-on-development/debugging-brooklyn-99-riddle-12-men-on-an-island-eca6cd4fce7).

Comment: Before you read a solution, you should work on it for another few weeks. It's a fun problem. Whether you figure it out or not, there is a really clever solution, if one phrases the problem in terms of 12 coins, which I read about when I was in school. It's in the great book "Professor Stewart's Cabinet of Mathematical Curious ties" by Ian Stewart. If you can find a copy it's a great read for a recreational mathematician. The solution: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/12CoinsInVerse.shtml